# How to simulate GCS for offline testing

Tags: c#, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a Python Google App Engine app which reads files from Google Cloud Storage, and I can test it offline with the local development server (dev_appserver.py), which is great.

I also have a .NET tool which dumps files into the cloud storage bucket for the App Engine app to retrieve, using `Google.Apis.Storage.v1.StorageService` based on the sample [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/api/StorageSample.cs).

This works fine for writing to the 'live' cloud storage, but how can I set StorageService to talk to the dev_appserver.py GCS simulator, so I can test the two tools together without using the live cloud services?

Alternatively, is there a different GCS local disk 'simulator' that I can use with both the .NET client libraries and the GAE local dev server?

Answer (score 0):

GAE GCS emulation uses the [github project called appengine-gcs-client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/python/src/cloudstorage/common.py).  It includes a check in a function called local_run() (inside common.py), which lets the api know if it is running locally or in production.

When running locally, the gcs-client uses an emulation url, returned from local_api_url().  This ends up looking something like:

http://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs

What I would suggest, is attempting to connect to the above url from your local .net application.  That should be sufficient to accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
def local_run():
  """Whether we should hit GCS dev appserver stub."""
  server_software = os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE')
  if server_software is None:
    return True
  if 'remote_api' in server_software:
    return False
  if server_software.startswith(('Development', 'testutil')):
    return True
  return False


def local_api_url():
  """Return URL for GCS emulation on dev appserver."""
  return 'http://%s%s' % (os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST'), LOCAL_GCS_ENDPOINT)

LOCAL_GCS_ENDPOINT = '/_ah/gcs'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Minio](https://min.io/docs/minio/container/index.html) as GCS replacement and run it as local docker container. It is not 100% compatible with GCS, but for simple things such as uploading and downloading, it'll work fine.

This is also a suitable solution for automated integration testing.